# Smart way or procedure to upperbound product of two summands?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, products, upper-lower-bounds

Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n$ be positive real numbers. I would like to handle products of this form:
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(a_i+b_i\right).$$

It looks like there are $2^n$ summands where each term has $n$ factors and $a_i$ and $b_i$ appear in them. Is there a way to handle/write down this product?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Upper bound in terms of what?

Comment: of $a_i$ and $b_i$. Or actually I am just wondering on how to write that down on a compact rigorous way.

Comment: Do you have a particular sequence in mind for $a_i,b_i$?

Comment: The $a$'s and $b$'s play the role of some expectations of powers of some normal random variables. I think it was something like $E[|x_1+iZ_1|^{\alpha_1}\cdots |x_n+iZ_n|^{\alpha_n}]$ where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a real vector and $Z=(Z_1,\dots,Z_n)$ is a normal vector with mean 0 and non-trivial covariance matrix $\Sigma$, $i$ is the imaginary unit, $|\cdot|$ is the complex norm and $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ positive powers. At the end I ended up having to estimate a product of sums, that's why I asked :) thanks for any hint you may have!

Comment: Misleading title. Please specify your question. For what purpose do you want to rewrite it? This form may be just good enough. It depends on what you want to be able to do with that sum. There is a way of writing this down as a $\sum$ over permutations.

Comment: I understand. I wanted to let it be as open as possible. The sum over permutations may be good enough. An alternative would be to use a triangle inequality on each factor but then how can one write it down in a nice and compact way without permutations?

Comment: You could try taking the log and estimating $\sum_i \log(a_i + b_i)$ instead.  Try to upper bound $a_i, b_i$ in terms of known functions and use calculus methods to get a bound on the sum.  The inequality $\log(x) \leq x-1$ could be useful if $a_i + b_i$ is close to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $[n]:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Then we can expand the finite product as
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a_i+b_i) = \sum_{A\;\subseteq\;[n]}\Big(\prod_{j\;\in \;A}a_j\prod_{k\;\in\;[n]\setminus A}b_k\Big).$$
You may want to list the subsets $A$ of $[n]$ in some particular order. Using permutations of $[n]$ gives similar but different orders.

We are given that $\;a_1,\dots,a_n\;$ and $\;b_1,\dots,b_n\;$ are positive real numbers.
Without more specfic information about these numbers, it is not possible to get an upper found on the product of the pairwise sums. One obvious example would be that if $\;a_i\le A,\;b_i\le B\quad \forall i\in[n]\;$ then the product is bounded by $\;(A+B)^n.$